# Vault Data offline persistence android api does not generate helper classes

Tags: android, contentful-api, contentful-vault

I am trying to use Android Vault API to get data from Contentful.
https://github.com/contentful/vault

However, when I call `requestSync()`, get an error that helper classes could not be generated. Does anyone have a same problem?

I am using gradle version 7.0.0 and Android studio version 2020.3.1

Here are dependencies for vault:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.contentful.vault:compiler:3.2.5'
annotationProcessor 'com.contentful.vault:core:3.2.5'
implementation 'com.contentful.vault:core:3.2.5'
```

Comment: hey, did you solve your problem? I'm facing the exact same issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin then you might have to replace `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`. Make sure you also have the required kapt plugin.